# Whether Cold backup method can be used to "migrate oracle DB"?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have to migrate one database.

I have exact server replica. Same directory structure on target as well as source database.

Previously I have performed DB migration using export/import datapump as we don't have access to any tools.
I want to ask whether I can create replica using cold backup method?

DB Details:

- Oracle 10.2.0.3 (On Both Source & target)
- DB is currently running in no archive mode.

Steps I am going to follow:

1. `create pfile from spfile`
2. `shutdown normal` on source db
3. Copy `pfile` to target server `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs`
4. Copy all the `dbf` , `ctl` , `rdo` files to target server (Using binary mode FTP) (`select name from v$datafile; select member from v$logfile; select name from v$controlfile`)
5. `startup pfile='<path>'` on target server

Doubts:

- Can cold backup can be used to create replica/ DB migration?
- If I tried above process, shall i am able to start the db on target server without any errors?
- As I don't have any archive logs, will that create any problem here?

Comment: Q no 1) Yes we can. Q no 2) Not enough steps, control just can not be ftp to destination. Q no 3) No, will not.

Answer (score 2):

> Can cold backup can be used to create replica/ DB migration?

Yes of course

> If i tried above process , shall i am able to start the db on target
>   server without any errors ?

If you had cloned the machine or installed Oracle binaries in destination machine, only you need another steps:

- Copy passwords file for your database, file $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapwSID
- Copy line of /etc/oratab describing the database you are cloning into
  destination machine.

> As i don't have any archive logs, will that create any problem here?

Yes its a cold backup, you don't need archivelog for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you do "ALTER DATABASE BACKUP CONTROLFILE TO TRACE;" and look in your trace directory undeer the diag directory, you will see a file that has all of the files associated with a database. If you weren't sure where all of the files are, this will help you to verify that.

[backup control file](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1225436401685)